# Не могу настроить ssh authentication Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-key

Доступ на удаленный сервер через  ssh authentication.

Сервер Ubuntu 19.10

Клиент Ubuntu 18.04

Порядок моих действий:

1.установка.

2.ssh-keygen

3.ssh-copy-id username@remote_host

Файл конфиг:

```
PasswordAuthentication no

PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile      ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2

PermitEmptyPasswords no

PasswordAuthentication yes (пробовал ставить no)
```

`sudo service ssh restart`

в терменале вывод после подключения:

> OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for 
>
>   *debug1: Connecting to ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх [ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх] port хххх.
>
>   debug1: Connection established.
>
>   debug1: identity file /home/ххх/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
>
>   debug1: identity file /home/ххх/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1
>
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 
>   Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
>
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat 
>   OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
>   debug1: Authenticating to ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:ххх as 'ххх'
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
>   debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>   debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
>    compression: none
>   debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
>    compression: none
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>   debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>   SHA256:KSaOztxaI0yRtf2cJkDezcJDYzA+bN4HOKXg+tlgmtY
>   debug1: Host '[ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх]:хххх' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/ххх/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
>   debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ххх/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
>   SHA256:rnvNuCkJjcQRe8Nc+veIBcxCQFFUtJn8KUEr9QHzHBA agent
>   debug1: Will attempt key: xxx@xxx RSA 
>   SHA256:oVqo/d7YxbssCGKOGtqHolijtnmvVOJC8NNEiu8DNb8 agent
>   debug1: Will attempt key: xxx@xxx ED25519 
>   SHA256:vkoHKso1Bq11BaueEopi0bAHUHGkprD8IxKwb9SM0/4 agent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
>   debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering public key: /home/ххх/.ssh/id_rsa RSA
>   SHA256:rnvNuCkJjcQRe8Nc+veIBcxCQFFUtJn8KUEr9QHzHBA agent
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Offering public key: xxx@xxx RSA 
>   SHA256:oVqo/d7YxbssCGKOGtqHolijtnmvVOJC8NNEiu8DNb8 agent
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Offering public key: xxx@xxx ED25519
>   SHA256:vkoHKso1Bq11BaueEopi0bAHUHGkprD8IxKwb9SM0/4 agent
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>   debug1: Next authentication method: password

Если в конфига  ставлю `PasswordAuthentication no`, пишет

> Permission denied public key.

В чем причина?

Comment: Конфиг менял или дефолтный юзаешь?

Comment: Может не тому user ключ положил ? Публичный ключ сверить желательно и можно . Или откатить конфиг дефолтный если ты бекапил